# O(n^3) complexity for function with if/elif/else statement

Tags: time-complexity

Consider the following pseudocode. It has an if/else/if statement. Within each conditional branch, there is a triple nested for loop. Is the complexity of this statement O(n^3) because the function can only take one path (namely if, elif, or else), or is it more complicated than that?

```
def myFunction(myVariable, myList):
    if myList == conditionOne:
        for sublist in myList:
            for element in sublist:
                for char in element:
                    print(char)
    elif myList == conditionTwo:
        for sublist in myList:
            for element in sublist:
                for char in element:
                    print(char)
    else:
        for sublist in myList:
            for element in sublist:
                for char in element:
                    print(char)
```

Comment: What's n? There are many different sequences in play here, is it the maximum length of any of them, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more complicated than that, but not necessarily due to the conditionals. Your current code does the same in every branch, and while your true code probably doesn't look exactly like that, it might be a good approximation. In this case, the difficulty stems entirely from elsewhere.

The complexity of your current code is the sum of the length of all elements in all the sublists. If `n` is an upper bound for the lengths of `myList`, every `sublist` and every `element`, then this is in O(n³), otherwise it may become complicated.

Another simple special case is:

- `myList` has length `n`.
- Every `sublist` has length at most `m`.
- Every `element` has length at most `k`.

Then your complexity will be O(nmk), assuming `n`, `m` and `k` to be positive.

Comment: A tiny, tiny correction: If k = 0, that is all the elements are empty, you still have O (nm) because the lists and sublists need to be examined.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you assume `n` is the length of the list `myList` (the number of sublist), then time complexity of your function not only depends on the length of the list `myList`, but also depends on:

- the maximum length of each sublist (the maximum number of elements in each sublist - the 2nd `for-loop` of each branching condition)
- the maximum length of each element (the number of char in each element - the 3rd `for-loop`)

Precisely, if `n`, `m`, `p` are respectively the length of your list, the maximum length of each sublist, and the maximum length of each element, then time complexity of your algorithm is O(n * m * p) in the worst case.

Comment: Yes, and any function in the set O(n\*m\*p) is also in the set O(max{m,n,p}^3).

Comment: If you have one list with one sublist with a billion characters, then O (max (m,n,p)^3) would be a very, very bad approximation. It would be true, but misleading. It's the difference between "my computer does it in a few seconds" and "no computer or computers in the world will every do this."

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of this code is actually `O(1)`. Regarding of which of the condition is true, and what is the length of the list, sublists and elements - you return immidiately after reading the first char.

If that's a mistake and you actually are iterating all characters, that's going to depend what is `n`, and there are two common ways to define it:

1. Usually when talking about time complexity, we define it in terms of the input. In here, your algorithm (assuming iterating all elements) is linear in the size of the input, so the complexity is actually `O(n)`. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Run-time_analysis): `Run-time analysis is a theoretical classification that estimates and anticipates the increase in running time (or run-time) of an algorithm as its **input size (usually denoted as n) increases**....`
2. If you refer to `n` as the number of sublists in `mylist`, and not the size of the input, and inh addition each sublist has `m` elements, each of length `k` (all on average). Then, the complexity is `O(n*m*k)`

Comment: I made a mistake returning the first character. I fixed that. Yes, n is the number of sublists in mylist.

Comment: This depends on the language. There might be languages where the keyword `return` behaves like Pythons `yield`. ;-)

Comment: @HermannDöppes Citation needed. I have never seen an article writing a pseudo code with `return` as `yield`, and for a good reason. (anyway, OP fixed his question and it seems to be a mistake, so second part of the answer applies)

Comment: 1) I haven't seen such pseudo code either. Which is probably a good sign.
2) I was just making the technical remark that making assumptions on the workings of an undocumented pseudocode is dangerous.
3) Even though I am guilty of that myself.
4) I never claimed anything to actually exist. No citations needed.

Comment: @HermannDöppes Assuming `return` is termination is just as assuming `for` is iterating (and not a single `if` condition). It makes no sense otherwise, and we have to have some conventions.

Comment: @amit Sure, some. And I agree, your comment (answer?) regarding the `return`s was justified. But the line between “some” and “to many” is hard to draw, is all I wanted to say.